# Object literals and event listeners, best practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-events

Suppose I have an object, with some properties and methods:

```
var Form = {
    name: 'sign-up',

    show: function() {...},
    hide: function() {...},
    validate: function() {...},
    updateCurrency: function() {...},
    handleCheckBox: function() {...}
}
```

Now I want to call different methods when certain events happen in my form like so:

```
$('#country-select').bind('change', function() {
    Form.updateCurrency();
});

$("input[type='checkbox']").bind('change', function() {
    Form.handleCheckBox();
});
```

I have a lot of these event listeners, and frankly, I find them ugly listed out one by one like that and not tied directly to the object they relate to.  Is there a more elegant way of encapsulating them within my object literal `Form`?  Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like `@gillesc` answer, it's on the right tracks. 
However, I think we can do better.

The main issue with `@gillesc` answer is that its missing the dynamic aspect of things (event handlers for instance), also it forces your to define ugly callback functions.

So heres how I think you should solve your problem.

```
// Test object
var testObj = {
    // Our event handlers. 
    // Notice how we must only define the callback function name here. 
    // Not the function itself. The callback function must be defined in testObj.
    handlers: {
        '#form submit': 'onSubmit'
    },
    // Method that will register all handlers to some selector
    registerHandlers: function() {
        var that = this;
        // Go through the handlers list.
        $.each(this.handlers, function(k, v) {
            // Parsing the event to two different parts. 
            // 1. trigger event
            // 2. selector
            var split = k.split(" "),
                el = split[0],
                trigger = split[1];

            // Delegating the trigger to selector
            $(document).delegate(el, trigger, that[v]);
        });
    },
    // Our actual callback function
    onSubmit: function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert("submit");
    }
};
```

How would it all work? Thats easy! We just need to call `testObj.registerHandlers()`.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E3xyz/)

Comment: Also whats good about this approach is that you are not forced to have registerHandlers method in your object. Did a really quick/dirty example of what i mean. [JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/E3xyz/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Organise your markup better and add classes to element that matches event handler methods so that you can easily create a list of handler and iterate over them to bind them to the targeted elements.

```
Var Form = {
    ....,
    handlers: {
        country: function() {},
        checkbox: function() {}
    }
};

$.each(FORMS.handlers, function(k, v) {
    $('.' + k).on('change', v);
});


<select class="country">....</select>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Then all you have to do is add classes and handlers to extend

Comment: This is perfect for generic handlers (attaching events via class names).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need to wrap your functions within more functions for a start.  Can't you just:

```
$('#country-select').bind('change', Form.updateCurrency);
$("input[type='checkbox']").bind('change', Form.handleCheckBox);
```

Comment: Yeaaah.. but that ignores other things I am likely doing within the callback such as preventDefault().  It also doesn't help me encapsulate my event handlers within the object like I want to do..

Comment: In which case you can wrap the bind method (and your bind method wraps your event handler), otherwise (in your example in your question), you're losing reference to the event, so how can `handleCheckBox` handle your check box?